# tempo da requisição em AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Bom faço uma requisição via AJAX, assim posso colocar um load na tela e removê-lo quando o AJAX carregar a pagina.

O problema é que preciso fazer o load aparecer apenas se a requisição demorar mais de 2 segundos.

Estou fazendo assim:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".loading").show();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'APP?pagina=<?= $pagina ?>',
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#app").html(response);
                    $(".loading").hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

`loading` é a DIV que contam o loading, e ela so pode aparecer se a requisição demorar mais de 2 segundos.

Alguém sabe fazer isso?

Comment: você conhece o timeout?

Comment: Sim tentei usar ele aqui mais estava dando errado, pois a div estava aparecendo depois de 2 segunda e não saia mais da tela. Acho que eu não estava fazendo da forma correta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dá pra utilizar um combo com status de variável e o `setTimeout`.

```
var showLoader = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
  var timeoutLoader = setTimeout(function () {
    showLoader = true;
    $(".loading").show();
  }, 2000); // 2000ms = 2 segundos

  $.ajax({
    url: 'APP?pagina=<?= $pagina ?>',
    success: function (response) {
      if (showLoader) {
        showLoader = false;
      } else {
        clearTimeout(timeoutLoader);
      }

      $(".loading").hide();
      $("#app").html(response);
    }
  });
});
```

1. Você cria uma variável de status do *loader*, deixando ela inicialmente como `false`.
2. Antes da chamada do AJAX, cria-se um *timeout* de 2 segundos e caso o tempo termine e a chamada AJAX não tiver terminado, o *loader* irá aparecer.
3. Quando a chamada finalizar, irá verificar o status do *loader* através da variável `showLoader`, se for `true`, esconde o *loader*, se não, limpa o *timeout*, para que ele não execute e mostre o *loader*.

Existem outras formas de fazer, mas essa é uma delas. Uma observação: 2 segundos é um tempo curto, veja se há realmente a necessidade disso na sua chamada AJAX, veja se ela demora muito ou é muito rápida.

Comment: Obrigado deu certo, em questão dos 2 segundos eu pensei assim. O site em média demora menos de 2 segundos para carregar, porém em relatórios pode demorar até 10 segundos, por isso quero que o loading só apareça quando a pagina demorar. Entendeu?

Comment: Tem um problema na sua resposta, o load não some da página.

Comment: Talvez tenha dado conflito no `clearTimeout` ao esconder o _loader_. Editei a pergunta e estarei escondendo o _loader_ mesmo se ele não aparecer.

Comment: ok vlw amigo deu certo